# Responsize height issues

Tags: css, responsive-design, height

So if you check out the link below you'll essentially see the goal I'm aiming for but as you can see, it's not perfect. I'm looking for the light blue box to load in with it's top centered with the outlined text block, and after scrolling, the bottom should align with the box. Hope this makes since, just having some trouble having this work on all screen sizes, any help would be much appreciated!

```
#home {
height: 50%;
margin-top:25%;
background-size: cover;
display:block;
position:relative;
background: #C7E2F3;    
}
```

Comment: Just made a few adjustment to allow the nav bar under the blue box to stick to the top. The problem I'm having now is getting the text box to get pulled when the nav bar hits it to bring it to the top as well